# Sending Data in String in Java instead of File

Tags: java

I am new to Java.I need to send a string over socket in Java.
As of now the code looks like below

```
public static void main(String [] str)
{

    String temp;

    try
    {


        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Z:\\ABC.txt"));
        String inLine = inputStream.readLine();

        System.out.println("Read String" + inLine);
        int k[] = new int[(inLine.length())/2];
        byte b[] = new byte[(inLine.length())/2];
```

Have to send the content of the file ABC.txt in string.Actually the file contains a string and have to send the same directly.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Need to send string directly over socket instead of reading from file

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to get a solution

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Operation
{
 static String serverName = "xxx.xxx.x.x";//ipaddress
  static int port = 9999;

public void writeTo(String fileContent)
{

     try
  {
     System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName+ " on port " + port);
     Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
     System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

     OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

     out.writeUTF(fileContent);


     client.close();
  }catch(IOException e)
  {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);

  }



}
```

Read the file content and store it into a String and pass to writeTo()

To read

```
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));
    try{

        String Myplaintext="";
        String currentline="";
        while((currentline=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            Myplaintext=Myplaintext+" "+currentline.toString();

        }
```

And call

```
 writeTo(Myplaintext);
```